# PyTorch ToTensor (F.to_tensor) quite slow, takes a long time

Tags: performance, pytorch, cpu-usage

Training a `resnet18` NN I get 100% CPU usage. Profiling my training loop (using `cProfile` and `snakeviz`) I notice that the call to `to_tensor` (1 in image) takes ~30% of the run time (2.7s of 8.9s on my profiling run). For comparison `Normalize` (2) takes 13% (1.2s), CPU-GPU copy (3) takes ~15% (1.3s) and running through the model itself (batch size is 256) takes only 2.25% (0.2s!). Interestingly, concatenating and transferring the loss values of each stage (a simple `torch.stack(...).cpu()`) takes a comparable time to CPU-GPU copy of 224x224 images.

CPU-GPU copy I can understand (though any tips on improving this are welcome). What I don't understand is how come `to_tensor` is so slow compared to all other operations. Why is this and how can I make the run more efficient?

[image: profiling results]